# What does the phrase 'Throw your Cap on It' mean and where did it originate?

Tags: etymology, phrase-meaning

In watching a recent soccer match, the commentator stated that the goalkeeper should 'throw his cap on that'.
This was immediately preceded by a relatively comfortable save by the goalkeeper from a tame shot.
Looking to gain understanding to the exact meaning and also where this phrase started.

Comment: I found [this Reddit comment:](https://www.reddit.com/r/FIFA/comments/3pgrcz/most_annoying_phrase_in_fifa_16/) *The one about the keeper being able to throw his cap on the ball. Get's said at least once a match.* Not familiar to me, but I'm guessing the idea is that the ball had a predictable / leisurely trajectory, giving plenty of time to throw a cap on/at it. That's to say, it was / should have been an ***easy*** save.

Comment: [...and again:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22throw+his+cap+on+it%22) *Bentley sends a dreadful effort sailing serenely towards Pyatov, who can throw his cap on it* (Feb 2009, Shakhtar Donetsk v Tottenham Hotspur - Uefa Cup).

Comment: Thanks for the comments FumbleFingers.

So your research also shows further examples in the sport of soccer. I wonder if this phrase is solely used for this sport,?

Also, the example provided is 2009, so seems like a relatively new phrase.
I wonder if other contributors can shed further light on this.

Comment: Per my first comment, if it *get's* [sic] *said at least once a match*, I guess some sports fans might be more familiar with the usage than I am. But I also found [*I reckoned {the goalkeeper} could have thrown his cap on it, which is **what we usually say when a shot is easy for the keeper**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thrown+his+cap+on+it+which+is%22)  Plus [*Everyone knows you have to throw your cap on the ice when a hometown player scores three goals,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22knows+you+have+to+throw+your+cap+on+the%22) but that's probably unrelated.

Comment: Anyway, many if not most of the references I found mention *British* football teams, so it's probably a relatively recent BrE usage. With pretty transparent meaning, as exemplified by [*The ball was swung into the six-yard box and, when it seemed the Newtown 'keeper **had time to throw his hat on it,** he instead stood and watched the ball pass him by and hit the upright.*](https://www.sportsouthdevon.co.uk/watcombe-win-cements-all-sdfl-premier-cup-final/) (***hat*** occurs as well as ***cap***).